# ng-repeat filter on certain field

Tags: angularjs, filter, ionic-framework, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a data like below:

```
[
 { id: 1, name: 'test', point: '2000' }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'bob', point: '1000' },
 { id: 3, name: 'hello', point: '3000' },
 { id: 4, name: 'xx', point: '4000' },
 { id: 5, name: 'zz', point: '1000' },
 { id: 2, name: 'fad', point: '1000' }
]
```

How to filter it by different points dynamically but not statically :

```
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { point: '1000' }"> 
<div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { point: '2000' }">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a point object on scope and update that in the controller and instead of the static value use the scope object instead.

Code For the same:

Controller:

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.items = [
 { id: 1, name: 'test', point: '2000' }, 
 { id: 2, name: 'bob', point: '1000' },
 { id: 3, name: 'hello', point: '3000' },
 { id: 4, name: 'xx', point: '4000' },
 { id: 5, name: 'zz', point: '1000' },
 { id: 2, name: 'fad', point: '1000' }
]
$scope.pointToBeFiltered = '3000';
});
```

HTML:

```
 <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    <div ng-repeat="item in items | filter: { point: pointToBeFiltered }">{{item}}</div> 
  </body>
```

[Working Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/8kQyt9tWqGiyaDO1UKiA)